# Postgres array as function input for where clause

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I've a table with `VARCHAR` as `PRIMARY_KEY`, so my IDs are randomly generated and looks like `WUoN5VemT` or `MQvOQidTi`. I just want write a function which expects an array as input and returns all elements which are contained in the array. I think the following semi-code will show better it a way better:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."getInfo" (
  "myIDs" varchar []
)
RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM "myTable" WHERE "id" IN($1) ORDER BY "idDate" DESC;
    -- RETURN etc....

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

But the problem is the array can contain 50 or more entries (100 are also possible), so I need to do this as fast as possible. The next problem is, the code above doesn't work. I often found the solution for multiple values using the `IN`-keyword, but is there any way to combine arrays and `IN`-clause?

Is there any chance to realize this using a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *long* arrays it can pay to unnest and join to the resulting set:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_info(_ids varchar[])
 RETURNS SETOF tbl AS
$BODY$
    SELECT t.*
    FROM   unnest(_ids) id
    JOIN   tbl t USING (id)
    ORDER  BY id_date DESC;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

This can be a plpgsql function, but an SQL function serves just as well.

@Clodoaldo already gave some advise on `STABLE` and the return type. My demo returns the whole row.

Don't just take my word on performance. Run a test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and, ideally report your findings. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error by adding "ODER BY id_date DESC":

Query failed: ERROR: column "id_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: ...OIN (SELECT unnest($1)) x(id) USING (id) ORDER BY "id_date" ^ QUERY: SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "myTable" JOIN (SELECT unnest($1)) x(id) USING (id) ORDER BY "myTable"."id_date" DESC) CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function "get_info".

For testing purposes, I'll count the results of the SELECT-statement. This will be replaced later...

Comment: @Nrgyzer: You changed the function (which I tested and it works) in an impossible way. You cannot `count(*)` and `ORDER BY id_date` at the same time. Please update your question with what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Ah, okay... I just removed COUNT(*) and it works, great... and thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM "myTable" WHERE "id" = any($1) ORDER BY "idDate" DESC;
```

This function is stable not volatile and it returns table or similar not varchar.